# Previewing an animation, without building BVH

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I am working on a scene in Cycles where neon lights are flashing. The materials are animated: using a mixshader to switch between a Emmission and Transparent node.

I want to preview the animation in 50% size and 32 samples, before rendering in HD, but this takes ages because every frame is building a BVH. I noticed in viewport rendering it doesn't need to build BVH per frame and only build it once. Is it possible to render this sequence like the viewport does (without building BVH per frame)?